# App install nightmare on Windows : Access denied / Deletefile failed code 5

Tags: delphi, windows-8, windows-7, inno-setup

I've been developing Win32 apps with Delphi for a long time, always installing them on %programfiles% folder. I use Inno Setup as my installation packer.

Since Windows 7 i'm having lot of trouble with customers logged with non-admin users. In such cases, when the user tries to install or update the app an error 'Access denied - Deletefile failed code 5' is returned.

Usually i tell the user to run the install app as administrator and then the install works.

The problem is this issue is becoming more and more common as it seems most Windows users nowadays do not log as admin and a lot of support is being demanded because this issue.

What is the best approach for it nowadays ?

Should i install my apps on %appdata% instead of %programfiles% ?

Thanks !

Comment: What version of Inno Setup are you using?

Comment: I used 5.0.3 for a long time, but yesterday i've updated to the most recent, 5.5.5

Comment: What flags are you using on these problematic files?

Comment: No flags in special, just overwrite the old .EXE by the new one. Because i updated only yesterday, i don't know yet if the new install package will solve the problem ; will wait for the feedback of the users.

Comment: So you haven't tested 5.5.5 yet by yourself? You're leaving it to your customers to test? 5.0.3 is most definitely your problem if that's the version you had this issue with. If it happened in 5.5.5 then you have another problem.

Comment: That's the problem ; the issue does not happens with all customers ; i could not reproduce the problem and could not determine the exact cause, so i'm assuming is the non-admin question

Comment: It's most likely the elevated privileges of Vista+ versions of Windows. Try raising the UAC level to max on your machine.

Comment: Software installations and updates are supposed to be done by a user with administrator privileges under UAC, so your software is behaving correctly. This has been the case since Windows Vista began enforcing UAC. Installing in %appdata% won't change anything (other than to make your installation wrong). The proper location is %ProgramFiles%, with the installation being done by a user with admin privileges.

Comment: If this is the cause, will the new version of Inno Setup handle it or i still will have the access denied error ?

Comment: You should not install in AppData - Program Files (x86 - if 32-bit) is correct. Does your installer have the words "Setup", "Install" etc in the filename? Windows uses those as a heuristic to grant the installer admin rights automatically, even if it hasn't got the manifest set up. Also, look in your setup EXE with a resource editor and examine the manifest, and compare it to a normal admin-rights manifest, to see if anything is different.

Comment: Definitely, this is the reason Inno Setup has many versions - rolling out changes to support later versions of Windows.

Comment: It has nothing to do with Inno Setup. Your installer is behaving properly, and changing the version of Inno Setup will change nothing.

Comment: @Ken So you're saying an Inno Setup version prior to Windows Vista knows how to properly elevate privileges?

Comment: Do not put your apps in the AppData folder. This folder has a different purpose, for what the name says: Application Data, not the actual apps.

Comment: @Jerry: No, I'm saying that there was no need to elevate privileges before WIndows Vista. All users could install software up until XP was introduced, and XP defaulted new user accounts to PowerUser, which was also allowed to install software. Vista introduced real UAC with restricted user privileges. Inno Setup did not change; the OS did. I can't believe neither of you were aware of this before now; UAC has been strictly enforced since before Windows 7 was released in 2009, and we're in mid-2015.

Comment: @Ken I'm not talking about XP or older Windows versions. I'm talking about older Inno Setup versions being used to install on newer Windows versions. Inno Setup certainly needs to be aware that it needs to be run with elevated UAC. You're actually saying exactly my point.

Comment: @Jerry: It doesn't matter what Inno Setup is aware of, as UAC is enforced by the OS. The OS will not let the install happen with UAC turned on without admin privileges, and the installer does not need to be aware of this requirement. **Windows enforces it**, and the installer doesn't have to do anything  special.

Comment: Your destination folder is fine. Do not change it (as long as you don't have serious reason for that). If the users do not have administrator privileges, some network wide administrator certainly does. That's the point of these restrictions.

Comment: @Jerry, to quote what Ken says, *Windows Vista uses methods to identify installation programs automatically and automatically prompts for approval of elevation when the application is run. This helps prevent common error messages and issues that users encounter when attempting to install programs, using standard user permissions.* ([`source`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc505883.aspx)). So the elevation should be prompted when the system detects an installer no matter what app. manifest contains.

Comment: So basically now that my Inno Setup is updated, these erros won't plague me again ?

Comment: I don't know, that's what I thought, now people seem to be saying otherwise.

Comment: The release history I linked above has tons and tons of references to improved elevation  handling in Vista+. 5.1.9: `Change in default behavior: The PrivilegesRequired [Setup] section directive now defaults to admin.`

Comment: Thank you anyway for your thoughts @JerryDodge . I will test and post the results here.

Comment: I ran into similar problems.  The initial install was handled by always making sure to set the install app to request admin privilages.  I use NSIS so am not familiar with the exact flag/define for inno.  I used to have each application update itself (via a config file stating where to get the update files).  But since Vista I have had to change that to have the updates be a complete Install application again so that the admin elevation can occur.  My main application gets installed to programFiles and any resource or user config files (and updates) have to go into %appData% so there is write

Comment: Definitely go for update, delphirules. Except new features, the recent versions knows about the file system and registry redirectors. @Jerry, I've just noted (if I was one of the people you were referring), that the elevation should be prompted automatically if the system detects an installer. If that actually happens I don't know. Update is definitely the way to go (not only because UAC, and redirectors).

Comment: @TLama I know Windows has recognition if the filename includes something like `setup` or `install`, but if the filename is like `MySoftware.exe` then I'm not sure how Windows would recognize it as an installer.

Comment: @Jerry, that's right. Here is [`the article`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc709628%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) I've had bookmarked...

Comment: @Jerry: If the app tries to write to %ProgramFiles%, regardless of whether WIndows identifies it as an installer or not, it needs administrative privileges. Period. Inno Setup has nothing to do with that at all - WIndows enforces it. Inno *can* include in the manifest that it needs admin privileges in order to get Windows to prompt for them. The point I'm making is that changing the Inno version is not going to magically make the "access denied* error go away. The user is still going to need admin privileges to write to %ProgramFiles%.

Comment: @KenWhite That's ok, my problem is the system does not ask for any privileges and simply block the install of this error message. If this new version of Inno Setup asks for admin privileges BEFORE the install, it's exactly what i want.

Comment: As long as you don't explicitly set `PrivilegesRequired` directive to something different from `admin` or keep your script without this directive specified, the setup build with the recent version of Inno Setup will ask for admin privileges. Your old setup did not meet the requirements for installer autodetection and so it was not asked for admin elevation by the system.

Comment: Which is exactly what I was saying when Ken shut me down.

Comment: UAC came out in 2005. You really need to learn about it.

Comment: If I remember correctly since Vista a program called Xxxx-Setup.exe should automatcially request admin privileges. What's the filename of your installer? https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd851376.aspx Oh, it's home only, enterprise versions disable this by default.

Comment: My setup file is named 'instalar.exe' ; should i rename to 'install.exe' ?

Comment: No, you don't need to. The recent versions of Inno Setup add in the output setup binary file manifest the `requestedExecutionLevel` attribute set to `requireAdministrator` value [`as long as you`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30872833/app-install-nightmare-on-windows-access-denied-deletefile-failed-code-5#comment49790913_30872833)...